# Can I install Visual Studio 2017 on Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I want to install Visual Studio 2017 on Visual Studio 2015. Is it possible or it will do a fresh install so my laptop machine will have two versions of Visual Studio installed? Also, I only need UWP Workloads of which SDKs and Emulator are already installed on my machine. Can anyone suggest whether it will upgrade my VS2015 or it will do a fresh install as an independent process?

Comment: Have you got this emulator issue been resolved. I am facing similar issue with Android Simulators.

Comment: I did a fresh install and it worked perfect for me. I only need Windows 10 emulators so not sure about Android.

Comment: And do you have VS2015 and VS2017 in same machine ?

Comment: Yes I have them in same machine, actually VS2017 doesn't support Windows Phone 8/8.1 projects so for that I need to use VS2015. Both works perfect for me , no issues faced till now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be a fresh install as an independent process.

Comment: But will it download windows 10 sdk again even if already installed?

Comment: It 'should not' as you can select within the install options to either install SDK or not see : http://www.lyalin.com/2016/11/27/installing-visual-studio-2017-and-ready-for-uwp-in-under-10min/

Comment: Ok, If the process stops in between then if I again start the process will it resume or install each component again?

Comment: I cannot confirm to be honest. But as the install time has been dramatically reduced if VS2017 it is not in my opinion that bad to start over anyway - but my opinion of course.

Comment: Thanks, one last query, after successful installation, I don't require 2015, so can we custom uninstall so it doesn't remove UWP SDKs and emulator ?

Comment: I cannot confirm on this either I am afraid as I have never tested this before but going from this article : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt720585.aspx it appears that if you run the standard uninstall it will leave separate installations as they are unless you perform Total uninstall.

Answer (score 0):

Normally different versions of Visual Studio install side by side.  One does not override the other.  So if you install 2017 and you already have 2015, you will have two versions of VS installed.  Each runs independent of the other.

Comment: If the process stops in between then if I again start the process will it resume or install each component again?

Answer (score 0):

I'm uninstalling Visual Studios (Enterprise) 2015 right now, as I'm going to install Visual Studios 2017 and space on my hard drive is a bit tight. You can, if you want, have both on your PC, if you have enough space. Shouldn't be a problem.
By the way, uninstalling can take quite a while...